# Is python a stable platform for facebook development?

Tags: python, api, facebook

I'm trying to build my first facebook app, and it seems that the python facebook ([pyfacebook](http://code.google.com/p/pyfacebook/)) wrapper is really out of date, and the most relevant functions, like stream functions, are not implemented.

Are there any mature python frontends for facebook? If not, what's the best language for facebook development?

Comment: What are you talking about, pyfacebook being out of date?  The page very clearly states that the project has moved to github, and the last commit date on github was on June 7th.  (http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tree/master)

Comment: I'm looked at github too - No signs of stream functionality there. I've linked to the google code page because the current documentation is still there. Thanks!

Comment: for what it's worth, the stream functionality is in the github version now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The updated location of pyfacebook is [on github](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tree/master). Plus, as [arstechnica](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/04/how-to-using-the-new-facebook-stream-api-in-a-desktop-app.ars) well explains:

> PyFacebook is also very easy to extend
>   when new Facebook API methods are
>   introduced. Each Facebook API method
>   is described in the PyFacebook library
>   using a simple data structure that
>   specifies the method's name and
>   parameter types.

so, even should you be using a pyfacebook version that doesn't yet implement some brand-new thing you need, it's easy to add said thing, as Ryan Paul shows [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~segphault/gwibber/template-facebook-stream/revision/289#gwibber/microblog/support/facelib.py) regarding some of the stream functions (back in April right after they were launched).

Answer (score 11):

Facebook's own Python-SDK covers the newer Graph API now:

http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/

Comment: This SDK is deprecated. It does not support the new cookie format that we rolled out as part of the OAuth Migration. In short, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try [this site](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tree/master) instead.

It's pyfacebooks site on GitHub. The one you have is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're a facebook newbie, I'd suggest doing your first couple of apps in PHP. Facebook is written in PHP, the APIs are really designed around PHP (although they are language-neutral, theoretically.) The latest API support and most of the sample code is always in PHP.

Once you get the hang of it, you can definitely write FB apps in other languages, including Python, Actionscript, etc. But my experience with other platforms is that they never work "out of the box" with Facebook the way PHP does.

This is nothing against python! I like the language alot.